# Classification problem where only future data has important missing values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I'm trying to work with a Gradient-Boosting Machine to work on a binary classification problem.

Given the following table of 4 columns where ColumnA is a binary value (0,1) that i am trying to predict

```
|  ColumnA  |  ColumnB  |  ColumnC  | ColumnD  | ... |
|     0     |
|     1     |
```

In the entire training data, I calculated the mean values and found that there is a large difference between the mean values of ColumnB when A is 0 and 1, so from my interpretation this means that this value should play a very important role in the prediction?

However when it comes to future data that I am trying to classify, I don't have any information about ColumnB. My question here is, does it make sense to simply take the mean value of columnB and provide that as the value for the future data, or should I entirely remove ColumnB since I cannot get that data in future values?

Currently I thought it would make sense to use the mean value as the default, but since that negates the effectiveness of the column in future predictions anyway maybe I'm doing this for nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on two things, first the relative weight or important that GB model is giving to column B. If the model is giving a lot of weight to `columnB` and it is a major deciding factor in your training set, then filling the null or missing values with the mean might result in bad prediction. Second thing is the number of missing values on `columnB`. If a lot of data is always missing in that column, say 30% or more, then it does not make sense to use that column as the model will be unreliable and your training data has no nulls in columnB so the model has never seen data with `null` and will be confused on making predictions.

You should test the feature importance in your model before you proceed. Check the accuracy without `columnB`. The last solution or an advanced solution will be to have a voting system model where you have multiple models, some with columnB and some without.